# utf8 doesnt works when adds a stylesheet

Tags: css, html, utf-8

Im trying to set `utf8` in `html5` running in windows over `Xampp`.

When I run the code without any stylesheets, it works great:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-ES">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    My Output Compañia 2014
</body>
</html>
```

And my output:

```
My Outpul Compañia 2014
```

But when I add in a stylesheet to the head:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-ES">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/test/css/style.css" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>
    My Output Compañia 2014
</body>
</html>
```

`Utf8` charset fails in output:

```
My Output CompaÒia 2014
```

Any Ideas to solve this? I tried with `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8` in `.htaccess`, declaring `utf-8` in the `css` but nothing works.

Comment: See if the font you are setting on body in your styesheets has compatible utf 8 character set and this specific character's code is mapped to the same character in your font.

Comment: @Arbel post it as a answer. It works

Comment: I did, great it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if the font you are setting on body in your styesheets has compatible utf 8 character set and this specific character's code is mapped to the same character in your font.

Comment: @StefanLuv You are welcome! Glad to be of help to you.